# high memory usage in .net program

Tags: .net, memory, garbage-collection, clr

It's a mix-code program(C#,C++), after run for one or two days, the memory usage is very high(1.5G)
    when i use windbg to dump the heap, i can't understand what cause that.
    first:  the gc heap size is only 338MB, but the memory Usage by RegionUsageIsVAD is about 1G(ps:i doesn't call virtual alloc in my program);
     second: the memory usage by RegionUsageHeap is about 550MB, then, i check the native heap, there's a lot of virtual block which size is zero, i don't understand where are the 550MB memory come from .
     the dump file analyze as below

```
0:000> !eeheap -gc                        
Number of GC Heaps: 1         
generation 0 starts at 0x7d138454    
generation 1 starts at 0x7d0eb434  
generation 2 starts at 0x00e61000  
ephemeral segment allocation context: none  
 segment     begin allocated  size  
00e60000  00e61000  01e4d5c4  0xfec5c4(16696772)  
073c0000  073c1000  083a3efc  0xfe2efc(16658172)  
............       
51e00000  51e01000  51f82b60  0x181b60(1579872)  
6b970000  6b971000  6bdd3764  0x462764(4597604)  
7d0a0000  7d0a1000  7d32cb00  0x28bb00(2669312)  
Large object heap starts at 0x01e61000  
 segment     begin allocated  size  
01e60000  01e61000  026784d0  0x8174d0(8484048)  
58d70000  58d71000  59080ef8  0x30fef8(3211000)  
Total Size:              Size: 0x142f30c8 (338637000) bytes.      
GC Heap Size:            Size: 0x142f30c8 (338637000) bytes.    

0:000> !address -summary
 TEB 7efdd000 in range 7efdb000 7efde000  
 TEB 7efda000 in range 7efd8000 7efdb000
 ......    
 TEB 7eeda000 in range 7eed8000 7eedb000  
 ProcessParametrs 006613d8 in range 00660000 00760000  
 Environment 006607f0 in range 00660000 00760000  

-------------------- Usage SUMMARY --------------------------  
    TotSize (      KB)   Pct(Tots) Pct(Busy)   Usage  
   3fa15000 ( 1042516) : 49.71%    57.71%    : RegionUsageIsVAD  
   11bf1000 (  290756) : 13.86%    00.00%    : RegionUsageFree  
    961e000 (  153720) : 07.33%    08.51%    : RegionUsageImage  
    30fe000 (   50168) : 02.39%    02.78%    : RegionUsageStack  
          0 (       0) : 00.00%    00.00%    : RegionUsageTeb  
   222cd000 (  559924) : 26.70%    31.00%    : RegionUsageHeap  
          0 (       0) : 00.00%    00.00%    : RegionUsagePageHeap  
       1000 (       4) : 00.00%    00.00%    : RegionUsagePeb  
          0 (       0) : 00.00%    00.00%    : RegionUsageProcessParametrs  
          0 (       0) : 00.00%    00.00%    : RegionUsageEnvironmentBlock  
       Tot: 7fff0000 (2097088 KB) Busy: 6e3ff000 (1806332 KB)  

-------------------- Type SUMMARY --------------------------  
    TotSize (      KB)   Pct(Tots)  Usage  
   11bf1000 (  290756) : 13.86%   : <free>  
    9edc000 (  162672) : 07.76%   : MEM_IMAGE  
    12d5000 (   19284) : 00.92%   : MEM_MAPPED  
   6324e000 ( 1624376) : 77.46%   : MEM_PRIVATE  

-------------------- State SUMMARY --------------------------  
    TotSize (      KB)   Pct(Tots)  Usage  
   60c4b000 ( 1585452) : 75.60%   : MEM_COMMIT  
   11bf1000 (  290756) : 13.86%   : MEM_FREE  
    d7b4000 (  220880) : 10.53%   : MEM_RESERVE  

Largest free region: Base 64d78000 - Size 02008000 (32800 KB)  

0:000> !heap -s  
LFH Key                   : 0x5733fdc1  
Termination on corruption : DISABLED  
  Heap     Flags   Reserv  Commit  Virt   Free  List   UCR  Virt  Lock  Fast   
                    (k)     (k)    (k)     (k) length      blocks cont. heap   
Virtual block: 08f80000 - 08f80000 (size 00000000)  
Virtual block: 08700000 - 08700000 (size 00000000)  
Virtual block: 0f480000 - 0f480000 (size 00000000)  
00660000 00000002    8192   6984   8192    156   224     4    3      0   LFH  
008a0000 00001002    1088    300   1088     17     5     2    0      0   LFH  
009f0000 00041002     256      4    256      2     1     1    0      0        
00490000 00001002    1088    300   1088     14     5     2    0      0   LFH  
00820000 00001002    1088    300   1088     17     5     2    0      0   LFH  
00280000 00041002     256     16    256      4     1     1    0      0        
00630000 00001002    1088    484   1088      6    14     2    0      0   LFH  
007c0000 00041002    1280    284   1280      1     7     2    0      0   LFH  
00930000 00041002    1280    388   1280      5    48     2    0      0   LFH  
03ab0000 00001002     256     20    256      3     1     1    0      0        
Virtual block: 173c0000 - 173c0000 (size 00000000)  
Virtual block: 17650000 - 17650000 (size 00000000)  
Virtual block: 17860000 - 17860000 (size 00000000)  
...............                                        
Virtual block: 48f00000 - 48f00000 (size 00000000)  
071b0000 00001002  120672 109376 120672    499   201    12  370      0   LFH  
08d30000 00001002   64000  13140  64000  11062   143    46    0      0   LFH  
    External fragmentation  84 % (143 free blocks)  
0fde0000 00001002     256      4    256      1     2     1    0      0
```

Comment: Are you using any unmanged resources in your program (ie Graphics Handles, Network/database/file connections, etc.) that are not being explicitly *Disposed* when no longer needed? Note that *unmanaged objects* **are not** garbage collected by GC, as it has no knowledge of such objects, and they must be explicitly released in a *Dispose* method in the controlling managed class.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens,there's no unmanged resources, and when i check the native heap with command "heap -s", it seems normal,but there are a lot of virtual block which size is zero

Comment: You could try the `dumpheap` (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2005/11/25/496973.aspx) for some details) command to get details about the objects you have on your managed heap.

Comment: @Christian.K,i have dump the manage heap , it's only 338MB